# How to established real time connection from local web server to live web server?

Tags: apache, nginx

is it posible to forward live web server from vps to web server in local machine?

ex. Live web server host in ovhcloud vps with public ip. then, there's local web server in my smartphone android with termux.

I want to use public ip from vps to forward to web server in my android.

can apache act as client real time establisted to live web server to receive forward request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could (for instance) forward your local port to your server using ssh

Enable ssh forwarding on server:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# add this to the config: 
GatewayPorts yes
service sshd restart
```

synatx is:

```
ssh -R <remote listen ip>:<remote port>:<local ip>:<local port> <your ssh host info>

ssh -R 0.0.0.0:9000:localhost:33334 localhost -p 2222
```

You can read more about this at https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example

Also, you could consider autossh to ensure the tunnel stays open even on weak connections find more about this at: https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/

I don't get the last question, tho.

Comment: so i need to run ssh server in vps. then my phone connect to ssh server? it makes my local web server in phone go public?

Comment: the reason i want to do this. 1. mobile carrier data, dont have fixed ip and port blocked. 2. protect database. If i use VPN or ssh ways. it still reveal database to vps. owner vps can access my database. if apache can act as client like websocket just for establised bi-directional connection waiting request live web server.

Comment: Yes it will forward a local port to your remote VPS, so it can access (and potentially forward requests to) your local port.

Note that you can choose what ports to forward, so if you just share your local web server then only the web server will be accessible from your vps (not your database).

Comment: but owner vps still can access database directly. and ssh slow down everything. browsing, play game in smartphone. there's no other ways just tunnel port 80. not intercept all connection?